# EaselJS sprite on("click) returns CORS error

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, createjs, easeljs

First off, I am working on a **local** EaselJS/CreateJS project, only to test some sprite and mouse interaction.

I have added a simple sprite image to the stage, and I called it "enemy1":

```
//Create the enemy sprite and add it to the stage
var enemy_image = new Image();
enemy_image .src = "enemy_sprite.png";
var enemy1 = new createjs.Bitmap(enemy_image);

enemy1 .x = 0;
enemy1 .y = 0;

stage.addChild(enemy1);
```

Using this code, I want to show an alert every time the user clicks on it:

```
enemy1.on("click", function() 
{
     alert("Clicked!");
});
```

Instead I get a cross-domain error on each click, as shown below:

[image]

**If the problem is that I am working local** or related to cross-domain requests - why does the picture load (and show) just fine on the stage, and the errors only show just as I click on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Canvas is perfectly happy to allow you to add cross origin data to it, but doing so (without CORS) will taint the canvas.

You get the error when you try to read data from the canvas while it is tainted.

Presumably the library you are using is trying to read the data as part of its code for determining what you clicked on.

Comment: So, if you'd like to add a click handler to an EaselJS sprite, how would you do it? What is wrong with my code? I believe it's pretty much textbook - assuming it works for sprites! Thanks for the info

Comment: I'd install a web server for development (something I'd do anyway because testing directly from a local file system is just too much pain in too many places)

Comment: If you're on a mac, there are super easy ways to start a web server, just open the terminal, `cd` to your project's dir and type: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`. You can now access your project on `localhost:8000`. As an alternative, you can use `php -S localhost:8000` and it will have the same effect. These commands should work on Windows if you have python or php installed.

Comment: BTW, I can confirm that the problem is that you're working local (`file://`). I tried your code on a webserver and it worked :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried it with a web server myself and it works fine. Since the error was showing during the event (and not during the image request), I didn't relate it to the web server.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41468523/773263) when trying to use images hosted on the web. Here is the function I wrote based on that answer as a work around:

```
function loadImg(uri) {
  var image = document.createElement("img")
  image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"
  image.src = uri 
  return image
}
```

Then do:

```
var enemy1 = new createjs.Bitmap(loadImg("http://example.com/enemy_sprite.png"))
```

Comment: Similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41468523/easeljs-cross-domain-images-workaround/41476881#41476881

Comment: @Lanny sorry not trying to steal your thunder, thanks for your help. Great product.

Comment: Not at all -- Your approach works just fine -- I had already written up the other one, and had additional details :) Cheers.