# EaselJs - cross-domain images workaround?

Tags: easeljs

When I try to use:

```
temp = new createjs.Bitmap(obj.path)
```

I get error:

```
Uncaught An error has occurred. This is most likely due to security restrictions on reading canvas pixel data with local or cross-domain images.
```

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665690/easel-js-security-restrictions-on-localhost-machine). Except in the above case user isn't using a web-server.

In my case I'm using a web-server but I need the images to be hosted on an AWS S3 bucket using https.

Is there a setting that I can use to allow CORS with EaselJs?

CORS Settings on S3 Bucket:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Edit: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35321609/773263)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bitmap does not handle CORS, since you must define a cross-origin property on your image directly *before* setting the src.

The best way to do this is to create the image yourself, and then apply cross-origin, before passing it to Bitmap.

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; // Should work fine
image.src = obj.path;
temp = new Bitmap(image);
```

There is currently no API on EaselJS to pass-through the crossOrigin, so this is the only way.

If you preload your EaselJS content with PreloadJS, you can pass the crossOrigin property on the queue, or any load item.

```
var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false, null, true); //3rd param
queue.loadFile("path/to/bmp.png"); // Will use the queue CORS
queue.loadFile({src:"path/to/bmp.png", crossOrigin:true, id:"image"}); // For one file only (you can leave out the param on LoadQueue)
// later
var bmp = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("image");
```

Note that the reason you get CORS errors even if the image displays is that EaselJS uses pixel fill to determine hit testing. You can also get around this by putting hitAreas on your images, which are used instead of the image pixels when doing hit testing:

```
var temp = new Bitmap(obj.path);
temp.image.onload = function() {
    var s = temp.hitArea = new createjs.Shape();
    s.graphics.fill("red").drawRect(0,0,temp.image.width,temp.image.height);
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try this tomorrow and I'll mark correct or post back with feedback. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Enable CORS on your [AWS S3](https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3) bucket under Permissions.

Comment: The image renders fine, but I still get the error. I don't understand why different permissions would be needed to see an image vs whatever easeljs is doing to get the pixel information for collision detection.

Comment: What does your browser's console say? Also study the network panel for clues. It's probably seen as less secure than a simple img tag as you're doing something with a remote resource in JS or something like that.

Comment: It works rendering but every time I click to drag I get the error posted in my question. I'm removing the JS tag from this question as it will likely require deep understanding of how EaselJs works.

Comment: Or maybe it's that normally it works because loading as img but to get pixel info it's maybe loaded as if it was JS? In this case maybe I need to double check my AWS S3 settings like you suggest. I will look into this more and let you know later.

Comment: Added my CORS rules on s3 bucket to question.